# How to replace +,/ and = from url on NGINX

Tags: nginx

I am sending encoded URL after replacing +,/ and = to NginX, but not able to replace them back on Nginx before decoding.
I don't wont to use something like php, which handle the request and response back from PHP server.
I want something in nginx only to manipulate string.
Till now I have tried with replace-filter-nginx-module and let module, but not get sucess.
Any help will be praised!

Answer (score 1):

Download Lua from http://luajit.org/download.html and unzip the folder. Then, run the following commands (remember to replace `[FOLDER_PATH]` by the actual place where you unzipped it):

```
cd [FOLDER_PATH]/
make
make install
```

**Lua NGINX Module**

Put inside add module in `./configure`
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/tags

Assuming NGINX is installed at `/opt/nginx`, run:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_ssl_module \ 
    --with-http_secure_link_module \ 
    --add-module=/opt/nginxdependencies/ngx_devel_kit-master \ 
    --add-module=[FOLDER_PATH]/set-misc-nginx-module-0.23 \ 
    --add-module=[FOLDER_PATH]/lua-nginx-module-0.9.10 \ 
    --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib'
```

Now download https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-string and add entry to `nginx.conf` above `server { ... }`:

```
lua_package_path "[FOLDER_PATH]/lua-resty-string-master/lib/?.lua;;";
```